# Flask framework: Deploying insert scripts to cloud

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, deployment

I am trying to deploy my flask code to AWS. I am unsure how can I migrate my insert scripts in Postgres to production.
I did find many tutorials explaining the use of flask-migrate to deploy schema changes but could not find enough solutions for deploying insert/update scripts. I have several lookup tables in my application for which I want to transfer the data within the table to cloud. Is there an efficient way to do this?

The scripts look something like this:

```
INSERT INTO tablename VALUES (1, 'USA');
INSERT INTO tablename VALUES (2, 'Canada');
.....
```

Currently, I am writing the scripts in '.sql' file and then running it on production using psql command. Although this solves the issue for now, I do not know if this is the best way to do this. Also it gets difficult to version control the scripts.

Any help would be appreciated.